# Firestore security rules, nested field

Tags: firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

Our database structure looks like that:

```
trips
   12345
      toArea
         radius: 150
         name: "citycenter"
   54321
      toArea
         radius: 250
         name: "main street"
```

We tried to create some rules for read from document:

```
match /chats/{trip} {
    match /messages/{message} {
       allow read, write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/trips/$(trip)).data.toArea != null
    }
}
```

**It's works fine**

but next rules doesn't works:

```
allow read, write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/trips/$(trip)).data.toArea != null
allow read, write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/trips/$(trip)).data.toArea.radius != null
allow read, write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/trips/$(trip)).data.toArea.radius == null
allow read, write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/trips/$(trip)).data.toArea["radius"] == null
allow read, write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/trips/$(trip)).data.toArea["radius"] != null
allow read, write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/trips/$(trip)).data["toArea.radius"] == null
allow read, write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/trips/$(trip)).data["toArea.radius"] != null
```

I really don't understand what wrong with it, how could two opposite rules (==null / != null) doesn't work. How could we manage with fields **toArea.radius** in rules?

Comment: try `.data.toArea.data.radius`

Comment: We are currently having an issue with nested properties in rules, this is almost definitely not your fault.  We're working on rolling out a fix as fast as we can, thanks for your patience!

Comment: would it be `.data.field.data` consistently?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT (12/18/17): These are both now fixed, so this should Just Work™.

As @hatboysam mentioned, you're currently hitting two bugs that we're working quickly to fix:

1. `get().data` only works if there's a reference to `resource.data` or `request.resource.data` somewhere in your rules (we used to support `get()` returning the `resource` without using `data`, but this ended up being problematic so it was changed right before release).
2. Nested properties (e.g. `toArea.radius`) are broken.

1 is easy to work around:

```
match /chats/{trip} {
    match /messages/{message} {
       allow read, write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/trips/$(trip)).data.toArea != null
    }
}
match /bogusPathThatWillNeverMatch {
  allow read: if resource.data != null; // should never be true
}
```

Both 1 and 2 will be fixed shortly, so stay tuned for resolution.

Comment: Could you point us in the direction of a bug tracker where we can subscribe to updates on this issue, @mike-mcdonald? :-)