# Firestore permission error when checking for sub-field in security rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm getting "Missing or insufficient permissions" when I have a security rule that checks for a subfield. For example:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /entries/{id} {
      allow read: if resource.data.business.id == "hh7AvLpTbFGRmCGodLV4";
    }
  }
}
```

The only document I have in `entries` collection:

```
{
  "batchId": "bnzVkufp9mM6yGokUYug",
  "business": {
    "id": "hh7AvLpTbFGRmCGodLV4"
  }
}
```

My query:

```
firestore()
  .collection('entries')
  .where('batchId', '==', 'bnzVkufp9mM6yGokUYug')
```

If I changed the security rule to `allow read: if resource.data.batchId == "bnzVkufp9mM6yGokUYug"`, it works fine. Is there something that I missed?

Note:

- The rule works fine when tested using "Rules playground" in Firebase Console, but failed in production.
- I have another project that works fine with rules that check for subfield. However, for 2 new firebase projects that I created, it doesn't work.
- I found a related problem from 2017 ([Firestore security rules, nested field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46961538/firestore-security-rules-nested-field)). Could this be the same issue re-appearing again?

Comment: Please edit the question to show both the exact contents of the document, along with the code that's trying to read it.

Comment: @DougStevenson, thanks for your quick reply! I updated my question with the info you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One important thing to realize is that [security rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters).

Right now, your rule is saying that all queries on the "entries" collection must specify a filter for `business.id` that equals "hh7AvLpTbFGRmCGodLV4".  The query you have now does not have that filter, so the rule is always going to reject it.  If you want the query to work with those rules, it will have to be like this:

```
firestore()
  .collection('entries')
  .where('batchId', '==', 'bnzVkufp9mM6yGokUYug')
  .where('business.id', '==', 'hh7AvLpTbFGRmCGodLV4')
```

Comment: Thanks, Doug! But, is this applicable, even if I only have **1 single document** in the collection that satisfies "business.id" == "hh7AvLpTbFGRmCGodLV4" ?

The doc says

"If a query could potentially return documents that the client does not have permission to read, the entire request fails"

but all the returned documents in my case (only 1 document) should be allowed by the security rule.

Comment: It doesn't matter.  If it's not a single document get(), the rule doesn't actually look at the contents of the document.  That simply would not scale like Firestore requires, when billions of documents could be involved.

Comment: Ah. I see! My impression is that ```resource.data``` in the security rule always contains the full document data. So, according to your comment, ```resource.data``` will only contain the fields that appear in the query? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: It's implicitly stated in the docs I linked you to: "Cloud Firestore evaluates a query against its potential result set **instead of the actual field values for all of your documents**".  If it can only look at the query, then yes, the data can only come from what the client sends.  If you find the documentation unclear, please use the "send feedback" link at the top right of every page.

Comment: maybe this is a naive question. What is the difference between ```request.resource.data``` vs ```resource.data``` if I can only get fields that appears in the query?

Comment: I think you might want to look over the API documentation for Request and Resource, play with it a bit,  then ask a new question if it's not clear.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource